# Mocking - Missing Method Invocation Exception

Tags: java, junit, mocking

I have a simple java program that has a service class that retrieves the current price of BitCoin in euros- BitCoinValueService.java. The `BitCoinPricer` class takes the number provided from the `BitCoinValueService` class and converts it to dollars.

The goal is to mock the object from the `BitCoinValueService` class because this number will fluctuate frequently.

Here is the test class code:

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class BitcoinPricerTest {

    @Mock
    BitCoinValueService bsp; 

    @Before
    public void initMocks(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMock (){
        BitCoinPricer bp = new BitCoinPricer(bsp);
        Mockito.when(bsp.findPrice()).thenReturn(6000.00);

        assertEquals(bp.convertEuro(bsp.findPrice()),6000.00,1.0);
        Mockito.verify(bsp).findPrice();
    }
 }
```

The Stack Trace:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
at com.bitcoin.BitcoinPricerTest.testMock(BitcoinPricerTest.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.runChild(JUnitParamsRunner.java:416)
at junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.runChild(JUnitParamsRunner.java:385)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

The code for the BitCoinPricer class

```
package com.bitcoin;

public class BitCoinPricer {

    static BitCoinValueService b = new BitCoinValueService();    

    public BitCoinPricer(BitCoinValueService b){
        this.b = b; 
    }

    public static  double convertEuro (double result){

        double euroVal = 1.227481; 

        result = b.findPrice() * euroVal;

        return result;

    }

}
```

Pseudo Code for BitCoinValueService:

```
findprice(){
    double result; 
    // do this

    return double result; 
}
```

I tried approaching it by having a dataprovider like this:

```
@DataProvider
public List<Object[]> dp(){
    final List<Object[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add( new Object[] {6000.00} );
    return result; 
}

@Test 
@UseDataProvider("dp")
public void testMock (double expectedVal) throws Exception{

    when(mockService.findPrice()).thenReturn(expectedVal);

    // Instantiate the object
    bcp = new BitCoinPricer (mockService);


    //Test begins 
    bcp.convertEuro(0);

    //checking condition
    assertEquals(bcp.convertEuro(expectedVal), 6000.00,0.1);

    verify(mockService, times(1)).findPrice();
}
```

However, I get a too many arguments exception.

Why Do I keep getting this misuse method invocation? I'm setting the price to come back as 6000.00. So, I can build my Junit tests around it.Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: remove `static`. why do you need static keyword for constructor param?

Comment: @utkusonmez The b.findPrice() is used in the converEuro() method in the BitCoinPricer Class.

Comment: Understood but there is no need for it to be static. make it a local field. and also no need to make the method static as well

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks I removed the static keyword. However, my assertion shows the actual value as opposed to 6000.

Comment: @utkusonmez I removed the static keyword. However, my assertEquals compares the actual value in real time and doesn't use the 6000.00 value?

Comment: `6000 * 1.227481  != 6000`

Comment: @traveler316 check your calculation and implementation

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding the logic in the method under test? what are you trying to do and what is the purpose of the parameter passed into the method?

Comment: @Nkosi I see. So, I updated the code to this: 'Mockito.when(bsp.findPrice()).thenReturn(6000.00);  
  assertEquals(7362.00,bp.convertEuro(bsp.findPrice()),1.0);'

It still doesn't equal the expected value?

Comment: @Nkosi I'm trying to set a value like 6000 that is outputted from the BitCoinValueService class. The number gets converted to dollars  i.e. 7364.886. So, the value from the convertEuro(bsp.findPrice()) should give me the expected value of 7364.886.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless that was a typo in the original question, the system under test needs to be refactored.

```
public class BitCoinPricer {
    BitCoinValueService valueService;

    public BitCoinPricer(BitCoinValueService valueService){
        this.valueService = valueService; 
    }

    public double convertEuro (){
        double euroVal = 1.227481; 
        double result = valueService.findPrice() * euroVal;
        return result;
    }
}
```

A test could then look something like

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class BitcoinPricerTest {
    @Before
    public void initMocks(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMock (){
        //Arrange
        double price = 6000.00;
        double expected = price * 1.227481;
        BitCoinValueService bsp = Mockito.mock(BitCoinValueService.class);
        Mockito.when(bsp.findPrice()).thenReturn(price);
        BitCoinPricer bp = new BitCoinPricer(bsp);

        //Act
        double actual = bp.convertEuro();

        //Assert
        assertEquals(expected, actual, 1.0);
        Mockito.verify(bsp).findPrice();
    }
}
```

Where the mock is arranged to behave as expected when invoked and an assertion can be made to verify that the method under test behaves as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In your case it is better just to create a mock in the `@BeforeClass` with `Mockito.mock(BitCoinValueService.class)` and reset it at `@After`. I assume your mock was not initiated correctly.